# module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments error in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

I have 3 files, factory_imagenet.py, imdb.py and imagenet.py

**factory_imagenet.py has:**

```
import datasets.imagenet
```

It also has a function call as

```
datasets.imagenet.imagenet(split,devkit_path))
...
```

**imdb.py has:**

```
class imdb(object):
def __init__(self, name):
    self._name = name
    ...
```

**imagenet.py has:**

```
import datasets
import datasets.imagenet
import datasets.imdb
```

It also has

```
class imagenet(datasets.imdb):
    def __init__(self, image_set, devkit_path=None):
        datasets.imdb.__init__(self, image_set)
```

All three files are in the datasets folder.

When I am running another script that interacts with these files, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tools/train_faster_rcnn_alt_opt.py", line 19, in <module>
    from datasets.factory_imagenet import get_imdb
  File "/mnt/data2/abhishek/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/datasets/factory_imagenet.py", line 12, in <module>
    import datasets.imagenet
  File "/mnt/data2/abhishek/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/datasets/imagenet.py", line 21, in <module>
    class imagenet(datasets.imdb):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

What is the problem here and what is the intuitive explanation to how to solve such inheritance problems?

Comment: `datasets.imdb` is a **module**, not something to use as a **base class**.

Comment: So how do I solve this?

Comment: remove `(datasets.imdb)`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> ```
> module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
> ```

This means that you are trying to inherit from a module, not from a class. In fact, `datasets.imdb` is a module; `datasets.imdb.imdb` is your class.

You need to change your code so that it looks like this:

```
class imagenet(datasets.imdb.imdb):
    def __init__(self, image_set, devkit_path=None):
        datasets.imdb.imdb.__init__(self, image_set)
```

Comment: So how do I solve this? How can I rearrange the files?

Comment: Perfect, bravo. Runs now ! Will accept answer in 5 mins !

Comment: Can you recommend a good read to understand these aspects of modules, objects and inheritance in Python please?

Answer (score 3):

Here's another possible cause...

If you have an `__init__.py` file, make sure you import the super class before the derived ones.

Here's the WRONG way to do it:

```
from mymodule.InheritedA import InheritedA
from mymodule.InheritedB import InheritedB
from mymodule.Parent import Parent
```

The above will give an error:

```
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

However this will work:

```
from mymodule.Parent import Parent
from mymodule.InheritedA import InheritedA
from mymodule.InheritedB import InheritedB
```

For example the file InheritedA.py might be:

```
from mymodule import Parent

class InheritedA(Agent):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def overridden_method(self):
        print('overridden!!')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `datasets.imdb.__init__(self, image_set)`
Your `imdb.__init__` method gets 3 arguments. Two you send and third is implicit `self`

Comment: Are you saying imdb should get 3 arguments? Or are you saying it is not getting 3 arguments? Is it is getting 3 arguments, which are they? I am passing only one, right (image_set?